# Amplify: Confirming domain ownership to add a custom domain

Tags: aws-amplify, amazon-route53

To move my React JS webapp into a domain that I already have I'm trying to follow the instructions to do this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/to-add-a-custom-domain-managed-by-a-third-party-dns-provider.html

But I can't follow them because it tells me:

> Configure a CNAME to point to the AWS validation server

But I can't do that because my DNS provider don't have any options to create a CNAME. I only have this and nothing else.
I can only change the name of the server which normally is something like dns1.hostingprovider.com and dns2.hostingprovider.com, nothing else.

I added the server name that I'm seeing in Amplify DNS record.

Hopefully somebody can see what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

[image]